# .Net Core configure start up for different builds

Tags: c#, build, .net-core

I'm trying to figure out an efficient way to configure my `Startup.cs` for different builds with out using a lot of nasty IfDefs.  If I were to configure a normal class, I would usually just swap out a component in the Dependency Injector and everything would be done, but since the startup class is used to configured DI, this isn't possible.

Currently I'm hard coding things like:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
     options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
     options.DefaultChallengeScheme = IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddIdentityServerAuthentication(AuthenticationRule.ConfigureForStaging());
//.AddIdentityServerAuthentication(AuthenticationRule.ConfigureForProduction());
```

I have a bunch of statement commented out throughput the code base

```
const string connection = @"Server=StagingServer.com;Database=MyStagingDB;Trusted_Connection=True;";
//const string connection = @"Server=localhost;Database=MyLocalDB;Trusted_Connection=True;";
```

This is not very efficient, and definetly error prone.  How can I configured my startup class to make switching builds easy?

Comment: You should most certainly be using different `appSettings.{Environment}.json` files. The fact that you hard-coded a connection string when by default it is taken from that file is worrying. Note that most configuration options accept a `Bind()` call that gets the data from the `Configuration` variable directly

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, Thanks I'll move something into there,  What should be done if I need slightly different behaviors though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one idea.

```
public class Program
{
    public static bool IsProduction = false; // shouldn't actually be hard coded.

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var hostCommon =
            new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseIISIntegration();

        var host =
            IsProduction
                ? hostCommon.UseStartup<StartupProduction>()
                : hostCommon.UseStartup<StartupStaging>();

        host.Build().Run();
    }
}
```

You could then put the common portions in a Helper class of some kind, and call whatever portions you need for each `Startup` class from each individual `Startup` class.

If you have more than two environments, you could use a `Dictionary<string, Type>` or `Dictionary<string, Func<IWebHostBuilder, IWebHostBuilder>>` and key off of the environment name.

Alternatively, you could use the Convention-based approach mentioned by  Camilo Terevinto. [From Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-2.1):

> An alternative to injecting IHostingEnvironment is to use a
>   conventions-based approach. The app can define separate Startup
>   classes for different environments (for example, StartupDevelopment),
>   and the appropriate startup class is selected at runtime. The class
>   whose name suffix matches the current environment is prioritized. If
>   the app is run in the Development environment and includes both a
>   Startup class and a StartupDevelopment class, the StartupDevelopment
>   class is used.

Comment: Isn't the default behavior that if you have `StartupDevelopment` and `StartupProduction` it will use the correct class depending on the environment detected? See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-2.1#environment-based-startup-class-and-methods) for what I mean.

Comment: @cwharris, thanks this is perfect, I've moved my configuration values to app settings,  But I have slightly different behaviors for staging and production so this will help out

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I imagine that isn't the case in this version of MVC, because you're expected to pass the startup class type explicitly. Maybe that existed in a different version where the Startup class was found via reflection?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto are you saying that If I just name the Classes that, the host will automatically resolve the startup file?

Comment: @johnny5 you could try it, but I highly doubt it'd work when using `IWebHostBuilder`.

Comment: @cwharris The docs still point to the exact same behavior on 2.1: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-2.1. The thing is that you don't need to call `UseStartup` explicitly

Comment: @cwharris Thanks,  I'll test it out, either way this resolves the issue.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Then why does the example key off of `HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment()` in the `Configure` method? Can you provide an example?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Thanks your right it will resolve it automatically according to the doc `if the app is run in the Development environment and includes both a Startup class and a StartupDevelopment class, the StartupDevelopment class is used. `

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Oh, you're right. You just exclude the `UseStartup<T>` and it finds the Startup class by convention. Didn't realize that.

Comment: Exactly, `Convention over Configuration` all over the place :)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Personally, I'd rather be explicit when the the convention doesn't actually provide that much benefit, and the configuration allows for more customization.